# Remove leading and trailing spaces from a Python list

Tags: python, json

I have a list being produced from a webpage using json.loads. I am displaying this with the following code:

```
myvar = json.loads(response.text)
print myvar[0],',',myvar[1],',',myvar[2]
```

This prints as:

```
0 , 1 , 2
```

What I would like it to print as is this:

```
0,1,2
```

I know I could achieve this by using `.strip()` if i converted each element of the list to a string first, but this is not a valid method for a dictionary. Is there a way to strip elements of a list without converting to a string first?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

At request of responder, here is the full code being used:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stagestatfeed'
        params = {
            'against': '1', 
            'field': '1',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'teamId': '32',
            'type': '7'
            }
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/Statistics/England-Manchester-United'}

        responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

        print '**********Shots Against (Action Zone) - Away:**********'
        print '-' * 170
        fixtures = json.loads(responser.text)
        print("%s,%s,%s" % (fixtures[0].strip(), fixtures[1].strip(), fixtures[2].strip()))
        print responser.text
        print '-' * 170
```

Comment: Would help to see what myvar is and what it contains.

Comment: Since no answer is pointing this out so far: The reason you're getting spaces in between your values is that the [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) with multiple arguments (`print a, b, c`) automatically inserts them for you: *"A space is written before each object is (converted and) written, unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of a line.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need this:

```
>>> myvar = [1, 2, '3']
>>> ",".join(map(str, myvar))
'1,2,3'
```

But, if you want to be more robust, then apply `strip` function to every element:

```
>>> myvar = [1, 2, '3']
>>> ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x).strip(), myvar))
'1,2,3'

>>> myvar = [1, 2, 3, ' 4 ']
>>> ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x).strip(), myvar))
'1,2,3,4'
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. that worked great. could you briefly explain to me though what the 'lambda' and 'x' do in the above though? thanks...

Comment: `lambda` - it is a short function. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/890128/821594) are some details.